# Let $Y$ be a metric space and $H \subseteq C(X,Y)$ equicontinuous. Then the closure of $H$ is equicontinuous too.

Tags: general-topology, equicontinuity

Let $(X, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, $(Y,d)$ be a metric space, and $H \subseteq C(X,Y)$. Then, $\operatorname{cl}(H)$ is equicontinuous too in the pointwise topology (subspace on the product topology $Y^X$).

**My attempt:**

We want to prove that $\operatorname{cl}(H)$ is equicontinuous in $x \in X$/

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $V \in \mathcal{V}_X(x)$ open such that for all $f \in H: f(V) \subseteq B_d(f(x), \epsilon)$.

Then, we have to find $W \in \mathcal{V}_X(x)$ such that $f(V) \subseteq B_d(f(x), \epsilon)$ $\forall f \in \operatorname{cl}(H)$.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p \in X$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ be given.
By equicontinuity, pick $V_p$, an open neighbourhood of $p$ such that

$$\forall h \in H: h[V_p] \subseteq B_d(h(p), \frac{\varepsilon}{3})$$

I claim that this $V_p$ also works for showing the equicontinuity of $\overline{H}$ (the pointwise closure of $H$ in $Y^X$) for $\varepsilon >0$, and to this end we let $f$ be any function in $\overline{H}$ and we I'll show that $$f[V_p] \subseteq B_d(f(p), \varepsilon)$$

and to this end, let $x \in V_p$ be arbitrary. (it's fixed for now.)
Then define $$O = (\pi_x)^{-1}[B_d(f(x),\frac{\varepsilon}{3})] \cap (\pi_{p})^{-1}[B_d(f(p), \frac{\varepsilon}{3})]$$

which is an open subset of $Y^X$ in the product topology (which makes all $\pi_q, q \in X$ continuous,in particular $\pi_x$ and $\pi_p$, so $O$ is a finite intersection of two open sets of $Y^X$, hence open). By definition $f \in O$, and as $f \in \overline{H}$, there is some $h_0 \in H$ with $h_0 \in O$.

The last fact implies that $d(h_0(x), f(x)) < \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ and also that $d(h_0(p), f(p)) < \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$ from the definitions.
Also, $h_0 \in H$ implies that $$h_0[V_p] \subseteq B(h_0(p), \frac{\varepsilon}{3})$$

So: $$d(f(p),f(x)) < d(f(p), h_0(p)) + d(h_0(p), h_0(x)) + d(h_0(x), f(x)) < \frac{\varepsilon}{3} + \frac{\varepsilon}{3} + \frac{\varepsilon}{3} = \varepsilon$$

where the two outer inequalities are from $h_0 \in O$ and the middle from the equicontinuity and $x \in V_p$.

As $x \in V_p$ was arbitary, we have indeed shown $f[V_p] \subseteq B_d(f(p),\varepsilon)$, as was required.

Comment: One question: we work on the space of continuous function, so shouldn't $O$ be open in the (sub)space of continuous functions?

Comment: @Math_QED No, we're taking the closure in the large space $Y^X$. Continuity of $h_0$ follows.

Comment: But I never work in the space $Y^X$. I work in the subspace of the continuous functions. But I can consider this subspace topology as the initial topology for the source $(pr_x: C(X,Y) \to Y: f \mapsto f(x))_{x \in X}$, so I don't think there's a problem?

Comment: We consider everything inside $Y^X$, which has two topologies we consider: compact-open and pointwise (product), the latter induced by the source of all projections (point-evaluations), the former is generated by the subbase of all $\langle K,O\rangle$, as we discussed before, and $C(X, Y)$ has the subspace topology wrt these two topologies.

Comment: The subspace topology wrt to the pointwise topology is then again initial wrt the restricted projections by the transitive law of initial topologies. The fun thing is that the total pointwise closure of $H$ stays inside $C(X,Y)$, while this does not hold for the space of continuous functions as  a subspace of $Y^X$. @Math_QED